# ViewPager with classes instead of layouts?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Basically what I'm trying to do is I want to have a ViewPager. 
But it should swipe between classes instead of layouts so that every page of the ViewPager has its own class where it also has its own stuff.

If you take instagram for instance. It has a BottomNavigationView where every item has its own acticity which handles its own methods and functions.
What I want to achieve is a BottomNavigationView like instagram which starts a new activity but with a slide animation to the left/right like with a ViewPager.

Comment: "But it should swipe between classes instead of layouts" -- `ViewPager` swipes between `Views`. Or, by use of `FragmentPagerAdapter`, it swipes between fragments. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html), and [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html).

Comment: View Pager is to display different Fragments, which means 'n' tabs and atleast  'n' fragments. what do you mean by swipe between classes ? Can you elaborate your your question more or show us what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @CommonsWare oh. i see... so its the wrong direction

Comment: `ViewPager` cannot be used to swipe between activities. I suspect that using multiple activities for your scenario will not work the way that you expect. But, you  are welcome to look into activity transitions as a way to implement your slide effect, and see if you can get something that looks the way that you want it to.

Comment: @CommonsWare I will. thank you :)